# Should I create tags for common components in proof assistant implementations?

Tags: discussion

I'm asking questions about certain type-checking phases of a proof assistant (`conversion-check`, `elaboration`, `pretty-printing`, `unification`, etc.). Should I add tags for those? There is another way to do it, which is to use the tag [implementation](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/implementation), but I'm not sure if it's encouraged.

Comment: When in doubt add a tag. I assure you if the community is not in favor of such you will get feedback.

Comment: I would just be careful with some of those tags, if you mean them for use with just *implementation* then I would hyphenate the tag with *implementation*. For many those would nice tags to use out side of implementation, but for those specifically interested in implementing a prover from the ground up, reading tens to hundreds incorrectly tagged items becomes a pain.

Comment: @GuyCoder See [my answer](https://proofassistants.meta.stackexchange.com/a/191/75) for why I think it is not a good idea to hyphenate tags in this way

Comment: To be clear, there is no problem with hyphenating `pretty-printing`, but with hypenation like `coq-unification`, `lean-implementation` etc.